# FQL Query for Stream returns no status messages for Friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying  use FQL to get status updates of all the users friends using FQL. The challenge I am having is that... while I **DO** get data for companies/Brands/People  the user likes or follows ...I get **NO** data for the users friends… I can see the users stream on facebook and its loaded with posts… but when I run the queries I get nothing… following are the queries I have tried…

> > **SELECT  source_id, actor_id,  post_id, message,description, comment_info.comment_count, like_info.like_count, created_time 
> >     FROM stream 
> >     WHERE filter_key IN ( SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() )**

I have tried the above query with an additional AND clause in the nested query e.g  ”type = ‘newsfeed’ / type = ' friendliest’

I have also tried…

> > **SELECT type, source_id, share_count, permalink, description, post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time
> >     FROM stream
> >     WHERE source_id in (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())**

I also added an AND clauses with various type e.g type ='56’

The following are the permissions granted to the assess token…

> > basic_info, create_note, export_stream, friends_status, photo_upload, public_profile, publish_actions, publish_checkins, publish_stream, read_stream, share_item, status_update, user_friends, video_upload

Baffling… I say... Baffling… please help…. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you switched the uid1 and uid2 fields in your friend subquery. You can try the following:

```
SELECT source_id, actor_id, post_id, message,description, comment_info.comment_count, like_info.like_count, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) and filter_key="app_2915120374" LIMIT 100
```

filter_key="app_2915120374" means "Status Updates".

Alternatively, you could use the Graph API liek this:

```
GET /me/friends?fields=statuses.limit(5)&since=1388530800&limit=500
```

will return you the last 5 status updates of your friends since 2014-01-01.

Comment: I tried the query above...now I can see 4 items of type "46" but its missing 20 other posts from a specific user...Which I can see on FB... can a user disable what can be seen by an external app...  Thanks for your help...

Comment: Also, when I add type = 46 in the second query above I can see 4 items...Basically it works just like your suggested query... the four items i see are checkins for a user... I still cant see the statuses for the user (whose checkins I can see)

Comment: why don't you use the filter_key I suggested?

Comment: Yes, also the limit...I cut and pasted your suggestion with no edits in the Graph API Explorer

Comment: Ok, but remember that the stream table doen't necessarily show all status of all users!